# Changing the data attribute of object tag to an SVG File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to change the data attribute of an  tag dynamically through Javascript, knowing that the value of this attribute is thoroughly an SVG file located in the server directory.

Basically i want to load a different SVG into that  depending in some user input. I tried `$('theObject').attr('data', 'FIleURL');`

I also tried the basic `document.getElementById('theObject').setAttribute('data', 'FileURL');`

The SVG just does not load knowing that if i place the url in the HTML directly it all works properly.

This is my HTML:

```
<object data="" id="theObject" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var theObject = document.getElementById("theObject");
            var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
            a.onload = function () {
                    //Do Stuff
            };
            theObject.setAttribute('data', '~/SVGs/SVGFile.svg');
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ does not mean your home directory when you use it within a web page.